# Rest api get endpoint with bind var in query

Tags: apex, query, rest, get

I want to bind variable in get request, but it gives me error "Bind variables only allowed in Apex code","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}". How to do it?

```
Account account  =  new Account(name = 'test');
request.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/query/' +
                '?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Account+WHERE+name=:account.name');
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? There's no need to callout to query your own org, and that Account has no Id because you didn't insert it. Please [edit] to provide context and clarity.

Comment: @DavidReed i am calling to another org. Account var i wrote just  for  here example, cause there are many code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the value directly in to the query string:

```
request.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/query/' +
            '?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Account+WHERE+name=\''+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(String.escapeSingleQuotes(account.name))+'\'');
```

You cannot bind to the variable in a callout, because it has to be interpolated directly into the string. This is a limitation of how HTTP callouts work in general.

Comment: got it, thanks.Seems good.